# Do I have an neutral wire? Could it be red?

Tags: wiring, switch, neutral, wifi

I'm trying to install a smart switch over the current 3-way 3 gang switch. I can't tell if I have a neutral wire as there are 2 red wires. One of the red is twisted with one other white wire.

After ripping the old switch off and tried hook one of the red in L and one in N on the new switch, and the switch came alive, but the buttons on the switch couldn't turn on the light l, here's a picture of the old switch

[image: old switch]

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and can you get us a photo that looks squarely into the wall please?

Comment: Your picture shows 2 disconnected wires. Where were they originally attached?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! So the red wire on the top goes into the first round switch on the bottom screw hole, and the wires on the bottom goes into the bottom round switch in middle screw hole

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but which one is the "first round switch"? Is that the "first" on top (from the picture's orientation) or the "first" on the bottom? Maybe edit your pic to draw some lines on it or reconnect them and take a 2nd pic.

Comment: Yeah, when asking about color coding, we definitely need to know what country you're in to give a proper answer, since it varies around the world.